# Make a query string link from a select dropdown?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'd like to build a simple url with a query string that works from a dropdown box with javascript/jquery.

Something like this...

```
<select id="query">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>

<a onclick="window.location='http://www.website.com/?title=' + $(#query);"></a>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the markup to

```
<select id="query">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>

<a id="anchor" href="http://www.website.com/?title=1"></a>
```

Then add some jQuery

```
$('#query').on('change', function() {
    $('#anchor').attr('href', 'http://www.website.com/?title=' + this.value);
});
```

that changes the href and adds the selected value to the URL's querystring